# Google in-app billing: Removing ads with a subscription

Tags: android, admob, ads

This is a more general question about Google's in-app billing mechanics. I've read the documentation, but there is one thing bothering me, that I would like to sort out before I get to coding.

I would like to remove Admob ads in my android application via a subscription. That means that the user pays for the subscription and as long as he/she chooses to keep the subscription active, there would be no ads in their application.

Now as far as Apple goes, they actually **forbid** the removal of ads via a renewable subscription. I've been browsing the webs for Google's view of this, but have yet to find any. If anyone has had any experience with this, please do no hesitate to share your thoughts. Am I allowed to remove Admob ads via a subscription.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can remove admob ads whenever you like. Using admob is 100% voluntarily and you can stop showing them in your app whenever you like.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I wrote to Google support, but only got some pre-generated generic response on how they cannot comment on that at the moment. Next to useless basically.

Comment: Is there any update on this?  I would like to do the same thing: remove ads via an subscription.